# jQuery, how in read Wordpress Contact form 7 AJAX JSON response from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using Wordpress Contact form 7 and want to customize its behavior. As I understand it uses jQuery form to submit a form and get response. I want to change it's 'success'/read behavior, to do that I need to know that `r()` function which is used by jQuery Form is executed and there was response from a server, perhaps I could read this response as well. But I can't figure out how I can find it is done, I know there is `$.when` function, but it does not help me, it does not see `r()`, perhaps it is located in another script and in another variable zone

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {
        $(function(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('.wpcf7-submit').click(function(){
                    //$(this).parents('.wpcf7-form')
                    //console.log( arguments.callee.toString() );

                    $.when( r ).then( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                                        alert( jqXHR.status );
                                    });

                    //$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                    //  // 0 === $.active
                    //});
                });

            });
        });
})(jQuery, this);
```

How can I find jQuery form is submitted? Can I read response from my function in another script?

Comment: whats r? i dont think that will be the correct scope, try jQuery.ajax instead there.

Comment: r() is a function of jQuery Form component. It is used to send/get data from a form. As I understand I should wait for it is done, then get it's JSON somehow and do whatever I need to do...

Comment: yea but it a local variable within the ajax function rather than a global object like jquery so you can't call it in your doc ready

Comment: How can I learn there was AJAX request and response then? I mean I click a button, it sends data, get response, I see it in console, can can I see it in my JS then?

Comment: you can try using the jquery ajax object in the parameters for when, but to be honest i dont like the thought of that, if you have other ajax functions it would run as well, can you not just make your own custom handler? just copy the current unminified contact form 7 js file with the ajax code, unhook it and make a new file with your ajax callback and hook that.

Comment: I like this idea because it makes my add-on universal, Jquery Form will not change in contact form 7, so if I add my handler to work with its objects, I will keep intact and updatable but add my functionality. All I need it to know when it sends data and catch response from a server. I thought it is not hard task when I started it. Do you mean to add form data to when?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
            if( e.currentTarget.activeElement.className == 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit' ){
            //console.log( xhr );
            if( xhr.responseJSON.mailSent == false ){
                var formID = xhr.responseJSON.into;
                /////////////////////////////////// to do something
            }
            }
    });
```

I think I found a solution via simple ajaxComplete, you can also put it Submit click event to avoid unnecessary checks. But I am not sure that will work find I mean ajax event will be handled before being actually sent. So I made simple ajaxComplete with a check of which element sends it and reading a response from a server. It works for me.

Comment: Just tested this out to catch an error thrown by W3 total cache on contact form 7. Works great! Thanks.